# Why is graphene the only (stable) 2D sheet structure?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, molecules, graphene, atomic-physics

I know that Carbon molecules can form different structures depending on how they bond with each other: graphite, diamond, graphene and fullerene. 
As far as I understand, graphene is just a "sheet" of carbon atoms, 1-atom thick.

Can't all atoms (not only Carbon) be arranged in such a way?

What is it that dictates the shapes of the possible structures of atoms/molecules?
I.e. why are those four carbon structures famous but no one ever hears about, say, Aluminium or Oxygen?

Comment: Found it: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110079/

Comment: Mica also forms in sheets...