# Why does graphene exist?

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, stability, graphene

I started to read some articles on [graphene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene) and almost all say that graphene was discovered late because physicists thought it would be unstable. Despite this, I didn't found a clear explanation of why graphene is indeed stable.

**Why does graphene exist, despite the [Mermin-Wagner theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermin%E2%80%93Wagner_theorem)?**

Comment: Maybe this paper could help you, but I imagine you will already have come across it, Intrinsic Ripples in Graphene. A Fasolino, J H los. M I Katnelson.

Comment: There's the answer in [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene#Structure): "Suspended graphene also showed "rippling" of the flat sheet, with amplitude of about one nanometer. These ripples may be intrinsic to the material as a result of the instability of two-dimensional crystals".

Answer (score 4):

The answer lies in the fact that, in graphene, there is an effective long range interaction mediated by the inverse biharmonic operator (which in 2D goes as $x^2\ln(x)$ and is *extremely* long-ranged) coupling the gaussian curvature at any two points on the sheet. Due to this, any static ripples or thermally produced dynamic ripples interact at arbitrary distances and allow for the existence of a flat phase (ordering of the normals). I have written an answer  [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/137281/34182) , which basically explains this point. David Nelson and Peliti did quite a bit of work on this in the 1980s, in the context of polymerized or tethered membranes (membranes with crystalline order).